# Safe Area Guide Not Appearing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I use XIB in most of my apps instead of Storyboards.  As you can see from the picture, I have Safe Area Layout Guide enabled as well as Auto Layout, but for some reason, my XIB still shows top and bottom layout guide instead of safe area.  What am I missing?  Ok, I changed to update recommended settings.  It still doesn't show Safe Area in the XIB file, but the app itself does seem to be respecting safe area.  Does this like the proper way this is supposed to be done?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On your warning list it says "Update to recommended settings", try that.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Ok I changed that, do the images in simulator above look like how apps should properly respect safe area?  It still doesn't show Safe Area, but it is behaving like it should I think.

Comment: Run the app on the iPhone X Sim. For each screen turn the phone screen to landscape left and landscape right. Check if any of your content is obscured by the face-recognition gizmo or the bar at the bottom of the screen. I can't tell if the text on the left on the third screen "Join us..." is too close to the edge of the screen. It might be. Also, look at the scroll indicators to see if they are in the right place for tableview/scrollview.

Comment: @PhoneyDeveloper Thanks.  It was a little too close.  Although the Safe Area guide doesn't show in hierarchy and still shows top and bottom layout guide, when I edited constraints, it allowed me to choose Safe Area as 2nd item for constraint.

Comment: Couple more tips. You can set an IB label for any views in your layout. It's on the pane that's the third from the left. It says Custom Class at the top and below Document and Label. Type a Label in there like 'Top Label' and that will be used by IB everywhere. Second, I like to have my constraints display from parent to child. I select a constraint then reverse first and second. So I would reverse trailing = background.png.??? When I do both these things the list of constraints is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 16):

Check on "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" from the file inspector.

[image: File inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me even if File Inspector shows "Use safe area layout guides" is checked.

I just unchecked "Use safe area layout guides", cleared the constraints, CHECKED back "use safe area layout guides", re-add constraints. Safe area is back.